# Symfony2: doing form validation before the form is posted

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

Going to try my best to explain this...

In my app I have the need to display the validation errors on a form when the user loads the form initially. In short, they've entered data and saved it, but now the data has been checked and we've detect errors they need to correct before they can fully submit the form. (It's multi step form that can be filled out over multiple sessions...think big.)

Previously I was doing something like:

**THIS DOESN'T WORK IN SYMFONY >=2.8.10** [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39605505/5441)

```
$entity // passed in as param on action method
$form = $this->createForm(..., $entity);
$csrfToken = 'random_string'; // retrieved from FormConfigInterface
// perform the submit but don't clear missing
$form->submit(['_token' => $csrfToken], false);
```

This was working, but seems to have broken in Symfony 2.8.10+, but works in 2.8.9. In 2.8.10+ there are no validation errors (the form is considered valid).

I'm able to retrieve the validation errors in a `ConstraintViolationListInterface`, but I can't find a way to "merge" that with the form (which I think would be the prefered way). Since I couldn't, I tried the above which "fake" submits the form...which seems like a bad idea.

Is there a better/proper way?

(Note: the form is much more complicated and includes validation groups...but I'm not concerned about that or the error in 2.8.10+ at this point.)

Comment: I can't quite reproduce your problem. I had a v2.8.8 app *lying around*. In very simply controller action I tried: `$form->submit([]);` after `handleRequest` but before `createView`. The rendered form shows all validation errors. I then upgraded to v2.8.11, and the behavior stayed the same.

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi I guess I'm trying to figure out first of all is if there's a better/proper way to get the validation errors to show up. If there isn't, then I'm going to try to debug what the form issue is in 2.8.10+ (the form has validation groups as well...so it's not exactly simple/easy to explain). Is the method above the "best" way?

Comment: "best way"? I don't know, it probably is the quickest way, though not the most semantic. If I wanted to clearly show that forcing the errors is intended, I probably start by investigating the `submit` method. But honestly, if this is the only occurence in your code where you need this behavior, just leave a comment to show intention. It already does everything you want with one method call.

Comment: @Yoshi I've figured out the issue (poss bug) and create another question with some details (before I submit a bug/issue): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603946/symfony2-entity-invalid-in-2-8-10-but-not-2-8-9