# Symfony2 entity invalid in 2.8.10+, but not 2.8.9

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

This is a follow-up to this question: [Symfony2: doing form validation before the form is posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382458/symfony2-doing-form-validation-before-the-form-is-posted) I've been able to simplify the code to create an demo.

Basically, I'm trying to get the form to display the validation errors before receiving a real form submission from the browser/user. When I do this in <=2.8.9, the form is considered invalid and shows the validation errors. When I do this in >=2.8.10, the form is valid. But when sending the entity through the validator, it still finds violations (same as in 2.8.9).

I've created a demo/example repo: https://github.com/darrylhein/symfony_form_validation_issue_2.8

Am I doing something wrong?

Did the API change internally somehow since I'm using "undocumented" portions?

I'm first trying to validate that there's an issue before I submit a bug report. I'd submit a fix or test as well, but I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: Only 10 files were changed in the validator. Should be easy to track down the problem. [v2.8.9-v2.8.10 comparison](https://github.com/symfony/validator/compare/v2.8.9...v2.8.10)

Comment: @keyboardSmasher thanks, this lead me right direction...I think I did this, previously, but didn't spend enough hacking time.

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be a change in the check to see if errors/violations can be added to a form. For some period of time (don't know how many versions) Symfony was allowing errors to unsubmitted forms and children, but in 2.8.10 this was changed with this commit: https://github.com/symfony/form/commit/498a795e875cbcb87511588e6619d5eb82c45f28

To work around this, I'm how retrieving the view data for each form field and passing that array into the `submit` method, as follows:

```
$fakeData = ['_token' => $token];
foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
    $fakeData[$key] = $value->getViewData();
}

$form->submit($fakeData);
```

I've also updated the repo: [the commit](https://github.com/darrylhein/symfony_form_validation_issue_2.8/commit/e74907defb12b3f8b218246dcd1eaf5123f5da4b).

**Note:** If you have data transformations on any of the fields, you may run into issues using the above code and you'll need to deal with them.

Comment: I've checkout out your code, and to me it seems your workaround directly works against what `$clearMissing = true` is doing inside the form-submit method. Meaning, you use `$clearMissing = false`, and then redo the work *by hand* that would otherwise be done inside the submit method. So the question would be, why do you need `$clearMissing = false`?

Comment: @Yoshi You're right, the `false` does nothing. I've updated the answer accordingly. ....unfortunately now I've realized that I have timezone issues in date times (getting the timezone in the users timezone)....so here goes more hacking.